# Rails 5 Barby gem does not print webpage with barcode html_outputter

Tags: barcode, ruby-on-rails-5, barcode-printing

I'm having some issue using Barby gem. It happens when I try to print the webpage. The barcode is showing on the page, but if I try to print, was not on the print preview. I'm using a liquid filter, so, the barcode is not directly called in the view, only when I use {{code | barcode}}

[image]

[image]

```
require 'barby'
require 'barby/barcode/code_25_interleaved' 
require 'barby/outputter/html_outputter'

module BarcodeFilter
 STYLE = 
   "<style>
     table.barby-barcode { 
       border-spacing: 0;
       border-collapse: collapse;
       width: 600px; 
     }
     tr.barby-row {}
     td.barby-cell { 
      height: 80px;
      padding: 1px;
     }
    td.barby-cell.on { 
      background: #000;
    }
   </style>"

  def barcode(input)
    begin
      barcode = Barby::Code25Interleaved.new(input)
      return STYLE + barcode.to_html
    rescue ArgumentError
      ''
    end
  end

end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(BarcodeFilter)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really late, but I was having the same problem for a while and I might as well share what worked for me.
I switched to using [JSBarcode](https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode). Just install it as you would any javascript file on a rails app, then call it like in the following example:

Javascript that generates a barcode based on the value of "item.reference_number" :

```html
<script>
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  JsBarcode("#barcode", "<%= @item.reference_number %>", {
    format: "CODE128",
  }); 
})
</script>
```

Outputs the barcode on your view here:

```html
 <svg id="barcode"></svg>
```

The generated barcode will be visible when you to print the webpage.

Comment: The problem has already been fixed some time ago. But still thank you for the help.